# I found a file path, but I can not open it

Tags: files, windows-subsystem-for-linux, paths

I am using ubuntu terminal on my windows 10. I cloned a project, and I have been working on it inside VSC for a week now. I finally closed the program, and when I open it again I could not find my files even in recent.

In ubuntu terminal, I found the directory and when I do `yarn run dev` the website opens with all the changes.

I found the path using `ls | xargs realpath` and but I can not find it in my computer to open it in VSC. this is the path /home/'my user name in github'/'project-name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "Ubuntu Terminal" you mean Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) you can find WSL files by entering the following in the Windows file explorer:

```bsh
\\wsl$\Ubuntu
```

Or, depending on your Windows version, simply:

```bsh
\\wsl$
```

You can find more info in this [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/q/1185033/1320563)